# cronjob error in OSX: "no path for address"

Tags: python, macos, shell, cron

I tried running a Python script using `cronjob` but I get the following error:

> cron[44405]: no path for address 0x10ff7a000
> in `grep cron /var/log/system.log`

When I ran the script *without* using `cronjob` it worked:

```sh
/usr/bin/python  /Users/anuj/Desktop/message.py
```

I tried adding the cron job using `$sudo crontab`.  This is the CRON script:

```sh
*/1 11-17 * * 1-7 /usr/bin/python  /Users/anuj/Desktop/message.py
```

Both paths are correct for root mode and user mode as I am running cron with `sudo`.

Comment: Odd. Looks related to: https://superuser.com/questions/1265765/cron-job-to-run-python-script-raises-error

Answer (score 0):

try to create file like `message.sh`
inside it run your .py file

```
#!/bin/sh
python path/to/python_script.py
```

and make this file executable with `chmod a+x message.sh`

`*/1 11-17 * * 1-7 path/to/message.sh 2>&1`